# Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ‘:compileApp’ of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

Im have upgraded my gradle version from 3.0 to 5.6.4, I’m encountering the following issue:

The following code works fine with Gradle 3.0

xyz.groovy:

```
project.tasks.create (type: JavaCompile, name: 'customTask1') {
        source <source dir>
        destinationDir <destination dir>
        classpath = project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    }.execute()
```

After upgradation, I get the following error:

`Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':compileApp' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.`

Now i know that the execute() has been deprecated in Gradle 5.
Im not sure on how to resolve this issue, Please help.

I removed the execute() and creating a new task:CustomTask2

```
project.tasks.create (name: 'CustomTask2') {
        source <source dir>
        destinationDir <destination dir>
        classpath = project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    }.finalizedBy(project.tasks."CustomTask1")
```

Now the error msg is resolved, but i dont see the compiled .class files in the destinationDir.

Comment: What is it you’re trying to do? If you want some additional files to be compiled, add it as source directory or add to the default source dir. executing a task is gradle’s job, not yours.

Comment: I have some .java files in the source dir and i would like to compile them and copy it to the destination dir. I have provided the classpath details as well, The task gets executed. But issue is, i dont see the compiled class files in the destination dir.

Comment: As I said, executing a task isn’t your job, it’s Gradle’s. Please read my comment again, the solution has been offered.